# pgpool2 not working on my Ubuntu i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux

Tags: postgresql, replication, pgpool, load-balancing

I am trying to implement replication and load balancing on my Ubuntu i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux.for creating database clustures I have installed postgresql contrib
9.1.11 having initially database clusture in directory `/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main`.

By using initdb command i have created two other database clusters under directories `/usr/local/pgsql/data` and `/usr/local/pgsql/standby` under port 5433 and 5434 respectively. Changes in `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` files of both clusters as follows:

In **`postgresql.conf`**:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
hot_standby = on 
log_destination = 'stderr' 
logging_collector = on 
log_statement = 'all'
```

In **`pg_hba.conf`**:

```
local   all             all                                    trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
local   replication     postgres                                trust
host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust
```

After that I have installed pgpool to by command `sudo apt-get install pgpool2`.
This installation create  directory in `/etc/pgpool` containing files as follows

```
pgpool.conf
pool_hba.conf
pcp.conf
```

Changes `pgpool.conf` as follows:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 9999
backend_hostname0 = 'localhost'                                  
backend_port0 = 5432                                   
backend_weight0 = 1                                  
backend_data_directory0 = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main'                                  
backend_flag0 = 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'

backend_hostname1 = 'localhost'                                  
backend_port1 = 5433                                   
backend_weight1 = 1                                  
backend_data_directory1 = '/var/local/pgsql/data'                                  
backend_flag1 = 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'

backend_hostname2 = 'localhost'                                  
backend_port0 = 5434                                   
backend_weight0 = 1                                  
backend_data_directory0 = '/var/local/pgsql/data'                                 
backend_flag0 = 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'
```

`pool_hba.conf` file as follows:

```
local   all         all                               trust
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
```

Make entry in pcp.conf of postgresql user with md5 password.
restart pgpool  /etc/init.d/pgpool2 start command and it started.

But when i am trying to use command `psql -p 9999` then it throws error as follows:

> bpsql: ERROR:  MD5 authentication is unsupported in replication, master-slave
>   and parallel modes.
>   HINT:  check pg_hba.conf**.

I have lot of googlee but I am not getting any solution.
Please help me to find solution and suggest me if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This exact error message is [in the FAQ](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/FAQ).

You have md5 authentication configured in `pg_hba.conf` and trust authentication (meaning no authentication whatsoever) in `pool_hba.conf`.

You need to configure either trust authentication or md5 authentication in both files.

Comment: thank a lot for your reply,but i had uninstalled pgpool2 and reinstall it by using apt-get install command.pgpool2 is starting but whenever i'm trying to execute command "psql -p 9999" then it is throwing error as:"psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.9999"?"  i am unable to find file "pgpool.conf".